# How to implement Wiegand Protocol in Android app

Tags: android, android-hardware, wiegand

I need to get data from external Hardware like Access Control Devices (RFID-Reader, Fingerprint Reader) through Wiegand Protocol in my android application.I have searched lot but didn't get any useful info.

Please help if anyone have any idea.Thanks in Advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use USB reader. It imitates a keyboard. Connect it to your phone via USB otg and you are ready to read the input